# BASH 4.4 showing key presses despite read using the -s option

Tags: bash, shell, echo

Strange use of BASH  I know but I'm building a game in BASH 4.4 script. The problem is that the map is displaying key presses both on the map and on the left edge. There shouldn't be any output from the read command because I'm using the -s option. The code for the project can be found here, https://github.com/neophyt1983/basch-crawl/
The relevant files are lungon.sh and map_lib.sh.

I'd be interested to know if anyone else sees what I've done that would cause this. Thanks for your help. So far I've looked over the code and been unable to find anything that should have caused this. I did try replacing echo with printf but that didn't fix it.

This is lungon.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

. mutual_lib.sh
. map_lib.sh
#. chr_lib.sh

#game_pid=$(echo $!)
plyr_x=0    # Players current x location
plyr_y=0    # Players current y location
c_x=0       # Players previous x location
c_y=0       # Players previous y location
quitter=0
finish=0    # Temporary
x=2     # Temporary
y=4     # Temporary

tput civis
map_builder
map_screen_draw
while [ $x -le $size_x ] || [ $finish -ne 1 ]
do
    while [ $y -le $size_y ] || [ $finish -lt 1 ]
    do
        if [ "${maps[$loc_lev,$x,$y,0]:0:1}" == "." ]; then
            plyr_x=$x
            plyr_y=$y
            c_x=$x
            c_y=$y
            tput cup $y $x && echo "@"
            finish=1
            break 2
        fi
        y=$((y+1))
    done
    y=0
    x=$((x+1))
done
while [ $quitter -ne 1 ]
do
    tput cup $plyr_y $plyr_x && echo "@"
    read -n1 -t 0.2 -s cmd
    case "$cmd" in
        w ) #Go Up
            if [ "$plyr_y" -gt 2 ]; then
                c_y="$plyr_y"
                c_x="$plyr_x"
                plyr_y=$((plyr_y-1))
                tput cup "$plyr_y" "$plyr_x" && echo "@"
                map_fill_path
            fi
            ;;
        a ) #Go Left
            if [ "$plyr_x" -gt 2 ]; then
                c_y="$plyr_y"
                c_x="$plyr_x"
                plyr_x=$((plyr_x-1))
                tput cup "$plyr_y" "$plyr_x" && echo "@"
                map_fill_path
            fi
            ;;
        s ) #Go Down
            if [ "$plyr_y" -lt $((size_y-1)) ]; then
                c_y="$plyr_y"
                c_x="$plyr_x"
                plyr_y=$((plyr_y+1))
                tput cup "$plyr_y" "$plyr_x" && echo "@"
                map_fill_path
            fi
            ;;
        d ) #Go Left
            if [ "$plyr_x" -lt $((size_x-1)) ]; then
                c_y="$plyr_y"
                c_x="$plyr_x"
                plyr_x=$((plyr_x+1))
                tput cup "$plyr_y" "$plyr_x" && echo "@"
                map_fill_path
            fi
            ;;
        q )     #Quit
            tput cup 1 1 && echo "Are you sure? y/n"
            read -n1 -s sure
            if [ "$sure" == 'y' ]; then
                quitter=1
            else
                x=1
                while [ "$x" -le 18 ];
                do
                    true
                    tput cup 1 $x && echo "e"
                    x=$((x+1))
                done
                tput cup "$plyr_y" "$plyr_x"
                tput bold
                quitter=0
            fi
            ;;
        i ) #Inventory

            ;;
        c ) #Consume 1,2,3,4,... Quick Bar

            ;;
        '<' )   #Up Stairs

            ;;
        '>' )   #Down Stairs

            ;;
        o ) #Open Door
            ;;
        c ) #Close Door
            ;;
        e ) #Enter
            ;;
        1 ) #Action 1

            ;;
        2 ) #Action 2

            ;;
        3 ) #Action 3

            ;;
        5 ) #Action 4

            ;;
        5 ) #Action 5

            ;;
        6 ) #Action 6

            ;;
        7 ) #Action 7

            ;;
        8 ) #Action 8

            ;;
        9 ) #Action 9

            ;;
        0 ) #Action 0

            ;;
        h ) #Help

            ;;
        ~ ) #Save
            ;;
        *)

            ;;
    esac
done

#read -n1
tput reset
exit 0
```

This is map_lib.sh
    #!/bin/bash

```
#trap "set +x; sleep 5; set -x" DEBUG
#Libraries
. mutual_lib.sh

declare -A maps
#declare -A maps_oper
declare -A map_error
declare -A NPC
map_err_count=0
tput bold
#NPC[0,0,0,0]=3     # This variable will hold a list of NPC's in the current stage

loc_lev=1
loc_x=1
loc_y=1
tput_x=$(tput cols)
tput_y=$(tput lines)
if [ $tput_x -gt 20 ] && [ $tput_y -gt 20 ]; then
    size_x=$((tput_x-2))
    size_y=$((tput_y-4))
else
    exit 1
fi
timer=1
top=0
btm=0
final=0
generated=0

map_fill_path()
{
    vis_x=$((plyr_x-1))
    vis_y=$((plyr_y-1))
    tput cup $vis_y $vis_x && echo "${maps[$loc_lev,$vis_x,$vis_y,0]:0:1}"
    tput cup $vis_y $vis_x && echo "${maps[$loc_lev,$vis_x,$vis_y,1]:0:1}"
    tput cup $vis_y $vis_x && echo "${maps[$loc_lev,$vis_x,$vis_y,2]:0:1}"
    tput cup $vis_y $vis_x && echo "${maps[$loc_lev,$vis_x,$vis_y,3]:0:1}"

    vis_x=$((plyr_x+1))
    vis_y=$((plyr_y+1))
    tput cup $vis_y $vis_x && echo "${maps[$loc_lev,$vis_x,$vis_y,0]:0:1}"
    tput cup $vis_y $vis_x && echo "${maps[$loc_lev,$vis_x,$vis_y,1]:0:1}"
    tput cup $vis_y $vis_x && echo "${maps[$loc_lev,$vis_x,$vis_y,2]:0:1}"
    tput cup $vis_y $vis_x && echo "${maps[$loc_lev,$vis_x,$vis_y,3]:0:1}"
    tput cup $vis_y $vis_x && echo "${maps[$loc_lev,$vis_x,$vix_y,10]:0:1}"
    tput cup $vis_y $vis_x && echo "${maps[$loc_lev,$vis_x,$vix_y,10]:0:1}"

    vis_x=$((plyr_x+1))
    vis_y=$((plyr_y-1))
    tput cup $vis_y $vis_x && echo "${maps[$loc_lev,$vis_x,$vis_y,0]:0:1}"
    tput cup $vis_y $vis_x && echo "${maps[$loc_lev,$vis_x,$vis_y,1]:0:1}"
    tput cup $vis_y $vis_x && echo "${maps[$loc_lev,$vis_x,$vis_y,2]:0:1}"
    tput cup $vis_y $vis_x && echo "${maps[$loc_lev,$vis_x,$vis_y,3]:0:1}"
    tput cup $vis_y $vis_x && echo "${maps[$loc_lev,$vis_x,$vix_y,10]:0:1}"

    vis_x=$((plyr_x-1))
    vis_y=$((plyr_y+1))
    tput cup $vis_y $vis_x && echo "${maps[$loc_lev,$vis_x,$vis_y,0]:0:1}"
    tput cup $vis_y $vis_x && echo "${maps[$loc_lev,$vis_x,$vis_y,1]:0:1}"
    tput cup $vis_y $vis_x && echo "${maps[$loc_lev,$vis_x,$vis_y,2]:0:1}"
    tput cup $vis_y $vis_x && echo "${maps[$loc_lev,$vis_x,$vis_y,3]:0:1}"
    tput cup $vis_y $vis_x && echo "${maps[$loc_lev,$vis_x,$vix_y,10]:0:1}"

    vis_x=$((plyr_x+1))
    tput cup $vis_y $vis_x && echo "${maps[$loc_lev,$vis_x,$vis_y,0]:0:1}"
    tput cup $vis_y $vis_x && echo "${maps[$loc_lev,$vis_x,$vis_y,1]:0:1}"
    tput cup $vis_y $vis_x && echo "${maps[$loc_lev,$vis_x,$vis_y,2]:0:1}"
    tput cup $vis_y $vis_x && echo "${maps[$loc_lev,$vis_x,$vis_y,3]:0:1}"
    tput cup $vis_y $vis_x && echo "${maps[$loc_lev,$vis_x,$vix_y,10]:0:1}"

    vis_y=$((plyr_y+1))
    tput cup $vis_y $vis_x && echo "${maps[$loc_lev,$vis_x,$vis_y,0]:0:1}"
    tput cup $vis_y $vis_x && echo "${maps[$loc_lev,$vis_x,$vis_y,1]:0:1}"
    tput cup $vis_y $vis_x && echo "${maps[$loc_lev,$vis_x,$vis_y,2]:0:1}"
    tput cup $vis_y $vis_x && echo "${maps[$loc_lev,$vis_x,$vis_y,3]:0:1}"
    tput cup $vis_y $vis_x && echo "${maps[$loc_lev,$vis_x,$vix_y,10]:0:1}"

    vis_x=$((plyr_x-1))
    tput cup $vis_y $vis_x && echo "${maps[$loc_lev,$vis_x,$vis_y,0]:0:1}"
    tput cup $vis_y $vis_x && echo "${maps[$loc_lev,$vis_x,$vis_y,1]:0:1}"
    tput cup $vis_y $vis_x && echo "${maps[$loc_lev,$vis_x,$vis_y,2]:0:1}"
    tput cup $vis_y $vis_x && echo "${maps[$loc_lev,$vis_x,$vis_y,3]:0:1}"
    tput cup $vis_y $vis_x && echo "${maps[$loc_lev,$vis_x,$vix_y,10]:0:1}"

    vis_y=$((plyr_y-1))
    tput cup $vis_y $vis_x && echo "${maps[$loc_lev,$vis_x,$vis_y,0]:0:1}"
    tput cup $vis_y $vis_x && echo "${maps[$loc_lev,$vis_x,$vis_y,1]:0:1}"
    tput cup $vis_y $vis_x && echo "${maps[$loc_lev,$vis_x,$vis_y,2]:0:1}"
    tput cup $vis_y $vis_x && echo "${maps[$loc_lev,$vis_x,$vis_y,3]:0:1}"
    tput cup $vis_y $vis_x && echo "${maps[$loc_lev,$vis_x,$vix_y,10]:0:1}"
}

map_cell_blok()
{
    #Cells are 4 by 4 walls with a door and blocks are 4 cells
    cb_x=$((cbt_x-8))
    cb_y=$((cbt_y-8))

    while [ $cb_x -le $cbt_x ];
    do
        maps[$loc_sel,$cb_x,$cbt_y,0]="$bar"
        cb_x=$((cb_x+1))
        maps[$loc_sel,$cbt_x,$cb_y,0]="$bar"
        cb_y=$((cb_y+1))
    done
}

map_column()
{
    #for making support columns
    true
}

map_dungeon()
{
    bar="W"
    #Dungeon Builder - this function will work out the usable space of the building area and fill it
    #with relevant structures and content.
    if [ "${maps[$loc_sel,$loc_x,$loc_y,0]}" != "e" ]; then
        odev=$set_x
        odd_even
        if [ $set_x -ne $odev ] && [ $set_x -gt $set_y ]; then
            true
        elif [ $set_x -ne $odev ] && [ $set_x -lt $set_y ]; then
            true            
        else
            true
        fi
        true
    fi

}

map_forest()
{
    bar="T"
    #Turns out that the original random wall placement works pretty well for a forest map

    temp_x=$((size_x-1))
    temp_y=$((size_y-1))
    loc_x=1
    wall=0
    if [ "${maps[$loc_sel,$loc_x,$loc_y,10]}" != "e" ];then
        while [ $loc_x -le $temp_x ];
        do
            while [ $loc_y -le $temp_y ];
            do
                top=100
                btm=3
                rando
                case $final in
                    1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|11|12|13|15|15|16|17 )

                        maps[$loc_lev,$loc_x,$loc_y,1]="${bar}000"
                        wall=$((wall+1))
                        ;;
                    21|22|23 ) #fallen trees
                        if [ "$maps{[$loc_lev,$loc_x,$loc_y,0]:0:4}" != "${bar:0:1}" ]; then
                            maps[$loc_lev,$loc_x,$loc_y,1]="t"
                        fi
                        ;;
                    30 )
                        maps[$loc_lev,$loc_x,$loc_y,2]="${maps[$Loc_lev,$Loc_x,$loc_y,0]}n100"
                        ;;
                        * )
                        maps[$loc_lev,$loc_x,$loc_y,0]='.000'
                        ;;
                esac
                loc_y=$((loc_y+1))
            done
            loc_y=2
            loc_x=$((loc_x+1))
        done
    fi
}

map_screen_draw()
{
    tput reset
    loc_x=1
    loc_y=1
    if [ $size_x -ge $(tput cols) ]; then
        max_x=$(tput cols)
        max_x=$((max_x-2))
    else
        max_x=$size_x
    fi

    if [ $size_y -ge $(tput lines) ]; then
        max_y=$(tput lines)
        max_y=$((max_y-2))
        #This seems to be an issue with BASH 4.4 so to avoid drawing the map on 1 more line than is available
        #I have to make sure that y never equals 43
        if [ $max_y -eq 43 ]; then
            max_y=42
        fi
    else
        if [ $size_y -eq 43 ]; then
            max_y=42
        else
            max_y=$size_y
        fi
    fi
    while [ $loc_x -le $max_x ];
    do
        while [ $loc_y -le $max_y ];
        do
            dep="${#maps[$loc_lev,$loc_x,$loc_y,0]}"
            n=0
            while [ $n -le $dep ]
            do
                #tput cup $loc_y $loc_x && echo "${maps[$loc_lev,$loc_x,$loc_y,0]:${n}:1}"
                #tput cup $loc_y $loc_x && echo "${maps[$loc_lev,$loc_x,$loc_y,1]:${n}:1}"
                #tput cup $loc_y $loc_x && echo "${maps[$loc_lev,$loc_x,$loc_y,2]:${n}:1}"
                #tput cup $loc_y $loc_x && echo "${maps[$loc_lev,$loc_x,$loc_y,3]:${n}:1}"
                tput cup $loc_y $loc_x && echo "${maps[$loc_lev,$loc_x,$loc_y,10]:${n}:1}" "$(tput bold)"
                n=$((n+4))
            done
            loc_y=$((loc_y+1))
        done
    loc_y=1
    loc_x=$((loc_x+1))
    done
}

map_builder()
{
    generated=$((generated+1))
    depth=$((depth+1))
    # Make the initial outline of the level based on the set size from size_x and size_y variables
    loc_x=1
    loc_y=1
    while [ $loc_x -le $size_x ];
    do
            maps[$loc_lev,$loc_x,$loc_y,10]='e'
            loc_x=$((loc_x+1))
    done
    loc_x=1
    while [ $loc_y -le $size_y ];
    do
            maps[$loc_lev,$loc_x,$loc_y,10]='e'
            loc_y=$((loc_y+1))
    done
    loc_y=1
    while [ $loc_x -le $size_x ];
    do
            maps[$loc_lev,$loc_x,$size_y,9]='e'
            loc_x=$((loc_x+1))
    done
    while [ $loc_y -le $size_y ];
    do
            maps[$loc_lev,$size_x,$loc_y,10]='e'
            loc_y=$((loc_y+1))
    done

    # Randomly select map type from a list and build
    top=2
    btm=1
    rando
    case $final in
    1 )
        #map_dungeon
        map_forest
        maps[$loc_lev,0,0,100]="dungeon"
        ;;
    2 )
        #This map uses randomly placed 'walls' or trees that go right up to the edge of the map container
        maps[$loc_lev,0,0,100]="forest"
        map_forest
        ;;
    * )
        #map_dungeon
        map_forest
        maps[$loc_lev,0,0,100]="forest"
        ;;
esac
}
```

Comment: Please don't expect readers to goto external sites to understand (and test) your problem. Please edit your Q to include the smallest sample of code that illustrates the problem. Good luck.

Comment: Specifically, in the close reason for question not having a [mre], note the text requiring the shortest possible code necessary to reproduce the problem be **included in the question itself**. Stack Overflow's scope is limited to narrow, specific, self-contained questions; we're not a "please go to my website and debug my code" service.

Comment: The two pieces of code are needed to test as far as I can tell. I have no idea what is causing the problem so I gave the minimum that I imagine to be necessary.

Comment: @Neophyt1983 Start by removing a line of code: if the problem disappears, put the line back and choose another; otherwise, remove another line and repeat. Keep going until you can't remove any more code without making the problem go away.

Comment: ...a process described in more detail at http://sscce.org/. Note that once you've done it properly, the result should be a program *clearly designed and built only to show this bug* -- not a program built to be a game, or a program built for any other purpose.

Comment: Also, while writing the smallest reproducible example of your issue, the cause of your issue may turn out very obvious, and you will help yourself.

Comment: The answer, not something a person would know unless they knew it. Does that solve the problem? No. Does it allow me to move on? Yes.